# SDL2 and Emacs setup

Tags: c++, macos, emacs, sdl, sdl-2

I've recently started using emacs for c++ code editing, on a mac, and was wondering if it's possible to use SDL2 with emacs. If so, how would one go about setting it up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You install the SDL2 development libraries and header files, then modify your build script to use them? Why do you think you need to configure Emacs? What problems do you have?

Comment: I'll go ahead and and use your guidance, I'm not having any problems other than with my own ignorance. Thanks a million.